# Catch Windows Messages from RadWindow : WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I have a requirement to override the Minimize function of the Telerik radWindow (clicking the Minimize Button on the Title Bar). Instead of the Window Minimizing to the bottom left of the screen I intend to simply reduce the Height of the Window leaving just the Title Bar showing (in the original position). Restoring the Window will again simply set the Height back to its original value to expand the Window….

So, I need to set Handle = true when the SC_MINIMIZE Message is received, this will prevent the Window from minimizing, then i can implement my own code to change the Height of the Window… This is the code so far…

```
    private void RadWindow_HostCreated(object sender, HostWindowCreatedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.HostWindow.SourceInitialized += HostWindow_SourceInitialized;
    }

    private void HostWindow_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var source = PresentationSource.FromVisual((Window)sender) as HwndSource;
        if (source != null) source.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(HandleMessages));
    }

    private IntPtr HandleMessages(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        // 0x0112 == WM_SYSCOMMAND, 'Window' command message.
        // 0xF020 == SC_MINIMIZE, command to minimize the window.
        if (msg == 0x0112 && ((int)wParam & 0xFFF0) == 0xF020)
        {
            handled = true; // not catching SC_MINIMIZE here
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
```

However, while I seem to be catching Windows Messages in the HandleMessages function, it is not setting handled = true; when I click the Minimize Button…

Any help would be appreciated…

Comment: Did you also try it without the bitwise and, like: `if (msg == 0x0112 && (int)wParam  == 0xF020)`

Comment: @lidqy Yep, tried everything there... I created a WPF App using a native WPF Window and that works fine. The Telerik Rad Window however, is hosted inside a WPF native Window so in the context of my example Code, 'e' is the Rad Window and HostWindow is the  WPF native Window. 

Then I add a Hook to listen for messages on the HostWindow...

My breakpoint on 'if (msg == 0x0112 && ((int)wParam & 0xFFF0) == 0xF020)' is getting hit BUT I never get the SC_MINIMIZE message...

Comment: Well I am not at all a pro in hooking window message loop  in WPF, so it's just shots in the blue, what I am saying...
Could it be they use different message/technique if the RAd window is hosted inside a real window?
There used to be a tool called **Spy++** (for WinAPI/C++ devs) in VS to monitor messages send to a certain window...
Don't know if it stills shipped with VS...